# using Navlink in react router dom but not loading the respected page (url is changing)

Tags: react-router-dom

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
function Header() {
    return (

        <div className='header'>
            <NavLink to="/">

                <img className='header_logo' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQMXl_zkdU92_MYc2tqty6pIjvG4JMAtJoQ5yA0dE4UfbS2R5l-RUiMczSNtQ1OAKcv-ZU&usqp=CAU'></img>

            </NavLink>

            <div className='header_nav'>
                
                
                <NavLink to="/checkout">
                    <div className='header_optionBasket'>
                        <ShoppingBasketIcon />
                        <span className='header_linetwo header_basketCount'>
                            {basket.length}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </NavLink>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

here after using navlink my url is changing but it not loading the components.Please someone help. I donot know where the problem is coming

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: NavLink is not loading the page, it is just changing the url. I have to refresh the page again to get the required page.

Comment: Are you rendering routes on paths that match what you are linking to? Can you edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Can you also verify the installed versions of `react` and `react-router` are installed by running `npm list react react-router react-router-dom` from the project's root directory and include those versions?

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled using below command :

```
npm install react-router-dom --save
```

I don’t know how it happened but "`--save`" works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by installing the latest version

```html
npm install react-router-dom
```